# Html. ActionLink: Passing CSS class and Id at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

So, this is how I tried to do it.

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Sprawdź","Details","Home",null,  new { @item.Id, @class = "btn btn-info" })</td>
```

But when I do so, I get Argument exception, because **ActionLink** Is not passing the Id. When I switch places of **null** value and annonymous class, the code works, but class is not applied. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried this to make it work

```
 <td>@Html.ActionLink("Sprawdź","Details","Home", new { @item.Id }, new {@class = "btn btn-info" })</td>
```

Created two annonymous classes, the first one passing Id, and second one passing the class. I leave the topic, maybe someone will find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work since on the 4th parameter, ActionLink is looking for **object RouteValues** which basically means that this values will be pass on your Controller. The next parameter (5th) are the **object HTMLAttributes** which will be the HTML attributes for your link element:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
string linkText,
string actionName,
string controllerName,
object routeValues, -- for passing values on your controller
object htmlAttributes -- for html attributes like css, etc.
)
```

So you need to change it to:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Sprawdź","Details","Home", new { intID = @Model.YourPropertyIdName }, new { @Id = Model.YourPropertyIdName, @class = "btn btn-info" })</td>
```

On your controller, it should match the property name on the parameter name.

**As you notice, I am passing intID on my ActionLink, so it should match on your controller as well**:

```
public ActionResult Details(int intID = 0)
{
  //TODO:
}
```